# django specify column arrangement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I am using Django ORM to create my database tables and perform the rest of the operations. However, I've noticed that the columns if I see in the database are not in the order I specify in the django models.

For example, my model is

```
class ItemMetaData(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE)
    field = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    field_value = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

But in the database when I see the table, the foreign key is the last column so it looks like

```
id | field | field_value | created_at | modified_at | item_id
```

I would like my item_id to be the first column after `id` . Like this:

```
id | item_id | field | field_value | created_at | modified_at
```

Is this possible? I tried to search but when I look for ordering all the answers assume it's row ordering and suggest using `order_by`

Migration file looks like this:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ItemMetaData',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('field', models.CharField(max_length=80)),                    
                ('field_value', models.CharField(max_length=80)),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('modified_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'app_item_meta_data',
            },
        ),
migrations.AddField(
            model_name='itemmetadata',
            name='item',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='app.item'),
        ),
```

Comment: I don't get why the order is relevant in the first place. Can you share the migration file? Likely one can alter the migration file and then migrate an empty database to respect the field order.

Comment: It's more of an OCD thing when I look at the database it seems absurd. Obviously when I query then I can specify the order of fields I want so it's not much of an issue. Let me edit the question to add the migration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this happens is because Django postpones creating `ForeignKey`s, `ManyToManyField`s, `OneToOneField`s, etc. after the models are constructed. Indeed, this is sometimes necessary, for example if you would construct models *M<sub>1</sub>* and *M<sub>2</sub>*, and they both have a `ForeignKey` to refer to each other. In that case one can not create the first model and create the `ForeignKey` in the same `CreateModel` migration, since at that time *M<sub>2</sub>* does not yet exists.

If you want to change the order of fields, you can work with a migration where you add the items after the `ForeignKey` is added, for example with:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='ItemMetaData',
    fields=[
        ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
    ],
    options={
        'db_table': 'app_item_meta_data',
    },
),

migrations.AddField(
    model_name='itemmetadata',
    name='item',
    field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='app.item'
    ),
),
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='itemmetadata',
    name='field'
    field=models.CharField(max_length=80)
),
migrations..AddField(
    model_name='itemmetadata',
    name='field_value',
    field=models.CharField(max_length=80)
),
migrations..AddField(
    model_name='itemmetadata',
    name='created_at',
    field = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
),
migrations..AddField(
    model_name='itemmetadata',
    name='modified_at',
    field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
)
```

If you then start from a empty database without any tables, it will normally put the `item_id` as second field.

That being said, usually the order of the fields does not matter (that much). Especially if you use the Django ORM to make queries, then Django will ensure that the columns are fetched in the right order to map these to model objects.

Comment: oh okay I understand your point. Thanks a lot! So this would mean I have to manually change the migration file which seems like something we should not be doing so I'll let it be. Thanks nevertheless!